# SQL Logical Operators -- Trying to get correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering what I am doing wrong with these operators.

I'm ultimately trying to get a list of people where one of the p.TEST OR p.DL is missing, but not both of them on the same person.

```
 select ....
  from ....

    WHERE

 ((p.TEST is null OR p.DL is null) OR
 (p.TEST = 0 or p.DL = 0) OR
 (p.TEST = 1 or p.DL = 0) OR
 (p.TEST = 0 or p.DL = 1))
```

Comment: what constitutes 'missing'.  Is it null, 0 or 1?

Comment: It's due to user input -- either null or 0 would constitute missing.

Comment: updated my answer to match

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me with this so quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ..
from ..
where 
    -- one missing 
    (isnull(p.test,0) = 0 or isnull(p.dl,0) = 0
    and 
    -- but not both
    not (isnull(p.test,0) = 0 and isnull(p.dl,0) = 0)
```

Comment: That is an awesome idea for future use---However, I'm just creating the report and I am not allowed to modify information.

Comment: @scottO I'm not modifying anything, what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, I thought that the isnull() would be replacing values --

Comment: Worked. thank you for that -- also kept it much smaller than I was originally trying.

Answer (score 1):

> but not both of them on the same person.

This is not guaranteed in your statements.

```
 ((p.TEST is null OR p.DL is null) OR  // if both are null this is true
 (p.TEST = 0 or p.DL = 0) OR           // if both are zero this is true
 (p.TEST = 1 or p.DL = 0) OR
 (p.TEST = 0 or p.DL = 1))
```

You have to explicitly check like:

```
((a is null) and (b is not null)) OR
((b is null) and (a is not null))
// etc. for zero values:
((a = 0) and (b  <> 0)) OR
((b = 0) and (a <> 0))
//...
```

And even then you will get results like `a = 0` but `b = null` so you may need to filter these too.

Comment: The people who input the information sometimes don't input anything, so I am checking for 'isnull' and '0'.

Comment: ((p.TEST is null) and (p.DL is not null)) OR
        ((p.TEST is not null) and (p.DL is null)) OR
        ((p.TEST = 0) and (p.DL = 1)) OR
        ((p.TEST = 1) and (p.DL = 0)) 
         AND NOT
        ((p.TEST = 0 OR p.TEST is null) AND 
  (p.DL = 0 OR p.DL is null))         --this is what i am trying now

Comment: @scottO this is absolutely a good practice, you can consider defining the table with such "non nullable" columns (if possible), this could make things easier for you.

Comment: I'm sure it would -- this is one of those where I have no say really. Only suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
 ( 
   (p.TEST is null AND p.DL is not null) OR 
   (p.TEST is not null AND p.DL is null)
 )
```

...and so on

This because you want to know when one is present and another is missing